# Strange behavior with Grid definition auto height and stacklayout inside the row

Tags: xamarin, grid, row, auto

I am using a grid with autoheight for row definition (I have a Editor inside, so my row can update it's height depending of the text).

My issue is, in another cell, there is a stack layout

```
StackLayout stackEspeceVariete = new StackLayout()
{
Children = { autoCompleteEspece, autoCompleteVariete }
};
stackEspeceVariete.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;

                 gridLignes.Children.Add(stackEspeceVariete);
                 Grid.SetRow(stackEspeceVariete, gridLignes.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
                 Grid.SetColumn(stackEspeceVariete, 2);
```

Adding the stacklayout cause my row to take all the screen size. I want the stacklayout to take the size it's needed, not all screen size.

I tried changing the vertical option but no success.

I also tried to fix the stacklayout height to 130, it's was "working" but, the row height was no longer changing, depending on the editor text.

It's like the row is fixed to the stacklayout child

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try to use two columns and set the `autoCompleteEspece` and `autoCompleteVariete` into different column and then use `ColumnSpan`  for the Editor.

Comment: Yeah I think I will do that. autoCompleteEspece and autoCompleteVariete  are linked, using stacklayout was great because they can be in the same column. But without the stacklayout, it's working great so ...

I am sure I am missing something basic, but what ?

I will try this later and see, thanks :)